# Unable to pass a value from the child VC to the parent VC using protocol/delegate

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, delegates, swift-protocols

I currently have a child VC added to the container view of the parent VC and I'm trying to pass a value to from the child Vc to the parent VC using protocol/delegate.

I created the protocol first:

```swift
protocol ChildToParentProtocol: AnyObject {
    func passValueToParent(value: Bool)
}
```

Then, equipped the parent VC with the protocol:

```swift
extension ParentVC: ChildToParentProtocol {
    func passValueToParent(value: Bool) {
        print(value)
    }
}
```

Created a segue from the parent's container view to the child view controller in IB named "childToParentSegue".  Then, added this to the parent VC:

```swift
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let vc = segue.destination as? ChildVC, segue.identifier == "childToParentSegue" {
        vc.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Finally , added this to the child VC:

```swift
weak var delegate: ChildToParentProtocol? = nil
@objc func buttonPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
     delegate?.passValueToParent(value: true)
}
```

When I press the button in the child VC, the parent VC is not receiving the value, even though the button is working.

**Updated**

I'm adding the child VC to the parent VC by using addChild(viewController) and viewController.didMove(toParent: self)

Comment: Looks good! So let’s try to debug. In buttonPressed when it runs, is `delegate` nil? Did the line `vc.delegate = self` actually run?

Comment: By the way you don’t really need a protocol for the child to talk to the parent. The button in fact could call right into the parent using a nil targeted action.

Comment: `delegate` is actually nil as you mentioned.  Does this mean the segue isn't set up properly? I'm adding the child VC to the parent VC by using `addChild(viewController)` and `viewController.didMove(toParent: self)`. Also, could you explain what a nil targeted action is?

Comment: I also set up an embed segue from the parent VC's container view to the child VC.

Comment: Ok so having an embed segue and using addChild(viewController) and viewController.didMove(toParent: self) are opposites, pick only one, segue or code. If you use code then set the delegate right there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I'm adding the child VC to the parent VC by using `addChild(viewController)` and `viewController.didMove(toParent: self)`.

That's the problem. There is no segue. You are presenting the child VC programmatically.

You should set the delegate at the same place as you present the child VC. I'm guessing you have some code like this:

```
let viewController = ChildVC(...)
addChild(viewController)
viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
```

Set the delegate after the above lines:

```
viewController.delegate = self
```